# How can I automate the capture and download of audio from a webpage?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

A few limitations first:

1. The audio isn't directly sourced, it's streamed, so identifying and downloading from a URL isn't an option
2. I've identified a Chrome extension (Smart Audio Capture) that circumvents this but I'm not sure how to automate its use.

I've tried approaching this using Python/Selenium and Webdriver but from what I've read, it doesn't appear possible to interact with the audio capture extension with Selenium.

Does anyone know of any ways in which to automate the use of browser extensions (Chrome or otherwise)? Alternatively, are there ways of capturing, downloading, and labeling audio files programmatically with something like Selenium or an alternative?

Comment: I think that [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) is the better alternative, it is newer than selenium, and doesn't require a webdriver. It works on chrome, msedge, firefox, chromium, and webkit, and I think the docs say that you can download audio files.

Answer (score 0):

For those curious, I've given up on using browser automation and am instead now using [PyAudioWPatch](https://github.com/s0d3s/PyAudioWPatch/blob/master/examples/pawp_record_wasapi_loopback.py) to capture all audio passing through a particular audio output device as well as the Tekore library to interface with the Spotify API rather than bothering with the web interface. So far, this has been working perfectly.

```
import tekore as tk
import time
import sys
from _spinner_helper import Spinner
import pyaudiowpatch as pyaudio
import time
import wave

AudioSegment.converter = "C:\\Program Files\\FFMPEG\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"

def capture_audio(trackName, DURATION, CHUNK_SIZE=512):
    filename = trackName+".wav"
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        with pyaudio.PyAudio() as p, Spinner() as spinner:
            """
            Create PyAudio instance via context manager.
            Spinner is a helper class, for `pretty` output
            """
            try:
                # Get default WASAPI info
                wasapi_info = p.get_host_api_info_by_type(pyaudio.paWASAPI)
            except OSError:
                spinner.print("Looks like WASAPI is not available on the system. Exiting...")
                spinner.stop()
                exit()
            
            # Get default WASAPI speakers
            default_speakers = p.get_device_info_by_index(wasapi_info["defaultOutputDevice"])
            
            if not default_speakers["isLoopbackDevice"]:
                for loopback in p.get_loopback_device_info_generator():
                    """
                    Try to find loopback device with same name(and [Loopback suffix]).
                    Unfortunately, this is the most adequate way at the moment.
                    """
                    if default_speakers["name"] in loopback["name"]:
                        default_speakers = loopback
                        break
                else:
                    spinner.print("Default loopback output device not found.\n\nRun `python -m pyaudiowpatch` to check available devices.\nExiting...\n")
                    spinner.stop()
                    exit()
                    
            spinner.print(f"Recording from: ({default_speakers['index']}){default_speakers['name']}")
            
            wave_file = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
            wave_file.setnchannels(default_speakers["maxInputChannels"])
            wave_file.setsampwidth(pyaudio.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
            wave_file.setframerate(int(default_speakers["defaultSampleRate"]))

            def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
                """Write frames and return PA flag"""
                wave_file.writeframes(in_data)
                return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)
            
            with p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                    channels=default_speakers["maxInputChannels"],
                    rate=int(default_speakers["defaultSampleRate"]),
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE,
                    input=True,
                    input_device_index=default_speakers["index"],
                    stream_callback=callback
            ) as stream:
                """
                Opena PA stream via context manager.
                After leaving the context, everything will
                be correctly closed(Stream, PyAudio manager)            
                """
                spinner.print(f"The next {DURATION} seconds will be written to {filename}")
                time.sleep(DURATION) # Blocking execution while playing
            
            wave_file.close()

# authenticate and create Spotify player object
conf = (CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET, "https://localhost:8888/callback")
token = tk.prompt_for_user_token(*conf, scope=tk.scope.user_library_read + tk.scope.user_modify_playback_state)
spotify = tk.Spotify(token)

# grab list of tracks in specified range from user library
startIndex = int(input("Start position in liked songs library: "))-1
tracks = spotify.saved_tracks(limit=1, offset=startIndex)

for track in tracks.items:
    duration = track.track.duration_ms / 1000
    name = track.track.name
    artist = track.track.artists[0].name
    songId = track.track.id
    print(f'Now playing: {name} by {artist}')
    print(f'Duration: {duration} seconds')
    spotify.playback_start_tracks([songId])
    capture_audio(songId, duration+1.2) # includes padding for playback capture delay
```

I also have added some additional code for converting to MP3 and adding tags, but that's slightly beyond the scope of my original question so I've omitted it in the interest of keeping the above example as simple as possible.

Comment: Besides the link, please share the code here. That is because the original repository could change or be deleted and then your answer could lost it's meaning

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).